# how do I initiate my jquery widget

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-widgets

I'm new to jquery, and I'm trying to build a widget that will populate a list on a page. However, I can't seem to figure out how to actually bind this widget when I click on a button. I also would like to run the widget when the page loads.

Here's my jquery widget that I've created (I'm not sure if any of this is right since I haven't tested it yet):

```
(function ($) {
$.widget('MyProj.conversationreply', {
    options: {
    },
    _create: function () {
        var self = this,
            o = self.options,
            el = self.element,
            $this = $(self.element);

        this.self = self;


        this.ui = {};
        this.ui.widget = $this;
        this.ui.list = $this.find('.reply-list');
    },
    _init: function () {
        this.Load();
    },

    Load: function () {
        var self = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: '/People/Conversation/ListReplies',
            data: self.postData,
            error: function () {
                self._error();
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            if (window.MyProj.isSuccessful(response)) {

                var html = [];
                $.each(response.list, function (i, item) {
                    var row = $(myProj.utils.template.GetTemplate('conversationReplyListItem').render(item));

                    html.push($('<div />').append(row).html());
                });


                self.ui.list.find('li').trigger('create');
                self.ui.list.listview('refresh');


                self._trigger("refreshed");
            } else {
                self._error(response);
            }
        });

    },



});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you explain what your widget is supposed to do and how it's intended to be used?

Comment: yes, my widget is used to populate a list of objects. I have an html page with an empty <li></li> and I want to load this widget each time a button on that page is clicked. Does this make my problem a little clearer? Thanks